# How to write SQL Statements With Spaces In Column Names

Tags: 8, database

I am trying to write a dynamic query to get data from columns with spaces in their names.

The *Product_Details* table is the following.

| S.No. | Product line | Product type | Product | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Camp Equipment | Cooking Gear | Cook Set | 2015 |
| 2 | Golf Equipment | Irons | Titanium | 2014 |

I am using this code, which returns a *syntax error or access violation* error.

```php
$query = \Drupal::database()->select('Product_Details', 'n');
$query->addField('n', 'S.No.');
$query->condition('n.Product type', 'Irons');
$results = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

While looking into the error log after the SQL Query has been executed, I found out this.

> 1: SELECT n.S.No. AS SNo FROM  {Product_Details} n WHERE n.Producttype
> = :db_condition_placeholder_0; Array (
> [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => Irons )

If you look into it, *Product type* is changed to *Producttype* and *S.No.* is changed to *SNo*.

How can I  write a SQL query when column names has spaces?

EDIT: This has been handled in the issue #[2986452](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2986452). This is committed to branch 9.0.x

Comment: You can use \`. `$query = \Drupal::database()->select('Product_Details', 'n'); $query->addField('n', 'S.No.'); $query->condition('n.`Product type`', 'Irons'); $results = $query->execute()->fetchAll();` According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190798/how-to-select-a-column-name-with-a-space-in-mysql you can use also `[]`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but backtick characters doesnt work gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally your column names shouldn't have spaces in them, but if you're stuck with that then you'll need to do a manual query, like this:

```
$q = \Drupal::database()
  ->query("select `S.No.` from `Product_Details` where `Product type` = 'Irons'")
  ->execute();
```